# Number of zeros of $f(z) =z^{87}+36z^{57}+71z^4+z^3-z+1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the number of zeros of the polynomial

$f(z) =z^{87}+36z^{57}+71z^4+z^3-z+1$

in the annular region $1 \leq$|$z$| $\leq 2$.

I did the exercise like this:
Let's say $f(z) =z^{87}+36z^{57}+71z^4+z^3-z+1$ and $g(z)=z^{87}+36z^{57}+71z^4+z^3$.

|$f(z) - g(z)$| $= |-z-1| \le |-z| + 1$

The largest value $z$ can take is $2$ so |$f-g$| $\le -2+1 = 1$ that is $\leq$ of $g(2)$.
So by Rouche's theorem $f(z)$ has the same number of zeros as $g(z)$, that is $0$.

Is it correct or not?

Comment: 1) How do you know how many zeros $g(z)$ has in the annulus?  
2) It's not enough to say $|f - g| \le g(2)$ on the boundary of the region;
you want $|f(z) - g(z)| < |f(z)|$ there.

Comment: 1) I thinked that $g(z)$ is sum of positive numbers (at worst I can have 1+36+71+1 when $|z| = 1$..so is positive.

Comment: Remember we're talking about complex numbers, so the terms are not positive.

Comment: ok.. so $|f-g|<|g|$ is wrog ? It must be $|f-g|<|f|$ ?

Comment: Actually the best version is $|f - g| < |f| + |g|$, but more commonly people use either $< |f|$ or $< |g|$.  But my point was that this needs to be true everywhere on the boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to break $f(z)$ into two functions $g(z), h(z)$ such that $f(z) = g(z) + h(z)$ and $|g(z)| > |h(z)|$ when $|z| = 2$

The number of zeros of $g(z)$ equals the number of zeros of $f(z)$ on the disk $|z|\le 2$

Then you want to do the same thing (i.e. different functions $g,h$) such that again $f = g+h$ and $|g|> |h|$ when $|z| = 1$ giving the number of zeros on the disk $|z|\le 1$

The difference will give the number of zeros on the annulus.

Comment: maybe I understand. I try to write something

Comment: For $|z|=1$ I take $f(z)=z^{87}+36z^{57}+71z^4+z^3−z+1$ and $g(z) =71z^4$. In fact $|f-g| = |z^{87}+36z^{57}+z^3−z+1| \leq 1+36+1-1+1 = 38 \leq 71$. So the number of zeros when $|z| = 1$ is$ 4$

Comment: For $|z|=2$ I take $f(z)=z^{87}+36z^{57}+71z^4+z^3−z+1$ and $g(z) =z^{87}$. In fact $|f-g| = |71z^4+36z^{57}+z^3−z+1| \leq  |z^{87}|$. So the number of zeros when $|z| = 2$ is $ 87$

Comment: In the end the number of the zeros on the annulus is  $87 - 4 = 83$

Comment: That all looks correct.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the dominant term on $|z|=1$ is $71 z^4$, the dominant term on $|z|=2$ is
$z^{87}$.

Comment: I used the hint, you can see the other comments